Save option not getting enabled during addition of user in AAS in azure
In azure portal, when I am trying to add any user as Azure Analysis Server Admin , I am unable to Save it as after selecting user Save option is not getting enabled neither newly selected user is displayed in the list of Azure Analysis Server Admin. Similarly unable to delete the user when any user is selected in portal.
